# Primefaces p:dataTable mudando mensagem default "No records found."?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

E tenho uma p:dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable var="ind" value="#{logIndPersistBean.list}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                        id="table"  rowStyleClass="odd-row, even-row">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Lista de Log
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column headerText="Name" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{ind.name}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Date" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{ind.date}" />
                        </p:column>

                        </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

Quando eu executo uma nova pesquisa, se não retornar nenhum registro, a dataTable exibe a mensagem  "No records found.", tem alguma forma de que eu não tenha que exibir essa mensagem, apenas a lista vazia ?

Eu sei que só preciso adicionar emptyMessage="", mas eu quero mudar a mensagem default, ou seja, ao invés de "No records found." para "Sua pesquisa não retornou nada" ou simplesmente "".

Existe alguma forma de mudar essa mensagem default ?

Eu estou usando primefaces 4.0.

[image]

Desde já agradeço !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com esse CSS você faz a linha default sumir:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-datatable-empty-message{
   display: none;
}
```

Não existe uma forma fácil de alterar a mensagem default sem alterar o código fonte do Primefaces, só com pequenos 'hacks'.

Comment: Obrigado, sua solução funcionou perfeitamente !

Answer (score 1):

"Simplesinho" meu brother, basta inserir em seu datatable emptyMessage
Dentro do emptyMessage você coloca a mensagem que você quiser.
exemplo

```
<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean.list}" var="obj"  emptyMessage="Nenhum Registro Encontrado" style="width:100%">
```

Abraço!

Comment: Como ele falou na pergunta, ele sabe dessa alternativa, mas ele quer mudar a mensagem default do componente dataTable, não só da tabela que ele fez.

Comment: Realmente me desculpem. Essa não é uma tarefa fácil meu amigo, como o nosso amigo Rafael informou.